# How to display a download link instead of displaying the file itself in php along with another form

Tags: php

I have a form to display which have file attachments at the time of form filling, I succeeded in attaching the file, but at the time of displaying the form it also showing the attached file in some binary/etc form, instead I want it to show just a file name and whenever we click on the file name it has to download the file... Please do help for this

My Code is:

```
<?php 
...
$id = htmlentities($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES);
// Get the details of the risk
$risk = get_risk_by_id($id);
$status = htmlentities($risk[0]['status'], ENT_QUOTES);
$subject = $risk[0]['subject'];
//file retrival fields
$filename = $risk[0]['name'];
$mimetype = $risk[0]['type'];
$filedata = $risk[0]['content'];
...
?>
<html>
...
<?php
...
echo "<label>Risk Assessment</label>\n";
echo "<textarea name=\"assessment\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"3\" id=\"assessment\" disabled=\"disabled\">" . htmlentities(stripslashes($assessment), ENT_QUOTES). </textarea>\n";
echo "<label>Additional Notes</label>\n";
echo "<textarea name=\"notes\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"3\" id=\"notes\" disabled=\"disabled\">" . htmlentities(stripslashes($notes), ENT_QUOTES) . "</textarea>\n";
echo "<label>Files attached:\n</label>";
echo $filedata;
...
?>
...
</html>
```

and the o/p is displaying the file content... :(

Comment: The partial code you shared isn't enough to clearly understand the problem. Please add more code..

Comment: it is a very big file, that's why I attached a lill bit code

Answer (score 0):

you are echoing the $filedata content. you should echoing the $filedata location, not its content.

Comment: how to give $filedata location, I don't know the file location

Comment: am saving my file in a table along with some other form filled details like risk, comments and many other fields, so how is my file will be seperated from all these @zimorok

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to download a pdf file instead of displaying it:

You're Page:

```
<a href="dl.php?filnam=xyz.pdf>Download the file</a>
```

dl.php

```
<?php
$filnam = str_replace(" ", "%20", basename($_GET['filnam'])); 
header ("content-type: application/pdf");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8'en'$filnam");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($_GET['filnam']));
readfile($_GET['filnam']);
?>
```

Comment: its working, but there is no file downloading, simply asking for download after that no download processed... :(

Comment: am unable to get the file downloaded, its asking for saving file, but nothing is happening after selecting save

Comment: That means it didn't find the file. Can you confirm that the file is in the directory that the href="dl.php?filnam=[file path/name]" is pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few steps

1. Get the name of the file
2. Get the local path of the file
3. Respond with a link.

It's been a while since I used PHP but I believe you can get the name of the file with

```
//basename takes /a/b/c/d.jpg and returns d.jpg

$filename = basename($risk[0]['name']); 
$localpath = $risk[0]['tmp_name'];
```

and then for your output do

```
echo "<a href=\"" . $localpath . "\"> . $filename . "</a>" . PHP_EOL
```

That will create a link with the label of the filename and the url of the local path on the server.

**Update**: Apparently the file doesn't actually exist yet. If this is the case, then you should write the contents of the file stored in your db. To do this, do

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "wb");
```

You can use whatever filename you want. You should add something like the timestamp or user ID or something to make the file unique so it's not overwritten by multiple requests. This will create the file. You can then fill in the file by doing

```
fwrite($handle, $risk[0]['content']);
```

finally close the file with

```
fclose($handle);
```

to output this new link you can just use the same filename if you like

```
echo "<a href=\"" . $filename . "\"> . $filename . "</a>" . PHP_EOL
```

If you specified the filename by including some unique value then you can get the original name by using

```
echo "<a href=\"" . $filename . "\"> . $risk[0]['name'] . "</a>" . PHP_EOL
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: my db doesn't have a variable named tmp_name...
I have name,size,type,content in my db

Comment: my db doesn't have a variable named tmp_name... I have name,size,type,content in my db @Paarth

Comment: thanks for the help, since am dumb at coding, am still unable to get it done...
I have made changes, while executing it showing the link to the file and when am clicking that link am getting error as "<filename> was not found on this server."

Comment: @santu47 So the server can only serve files that exist. As you have things, the files are stored in the database so there is no physical file at the moment. What I'm doing in the Update portion of my post is creating such a file with the name of the entry from the database and the content of the content from the database. First I create a file with that name, and then I fill it using fwrite with the content of the database. Closing the file is a formality. Now that this file exists, I can serve it up. In a simple case you can ignore my message about adding something unique.

Comment: @santu47 The 'something unique' only applied if you meant for this code to be used everywhere. I mention this because if you didn't make the name unique, then if two people tried to access the same filename at once they would experience a race condition and they would both get the same file, but we wouldn't be able to tell whose it was.